# Why does my 'Delete Case' action in the case search report not work?

Tags: custom-fields, civicase, reports

When I use the 'Find Cases' report (from the Case menu), and I select [Delete Cases] it does nothing. And it looks de different. Like this: [image]

CiviCRM version  5.34.alpha1 on Drupal:

And besides that, the search part looked funny too:[image]
The search *from* and the *to* fields are visible.

In the JavaScript console I see the following message in red:

```
select2.min.js?qmiq9r:75 Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 custom_13_from
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with an added custom field. See: [image]

Its a range *and* an option list.

Workaround.

- Go to the custom field definition (it's somewhere on cases, for techies, you can find the id in the javascript error.
- Change the Field Input Type to *Single Line Input Field*
- Now *Search by Range* is visible. Uncheck it.
- Set the 'Field Input Type' back to the former value.
- And save.

The case report should by back to normal.

Comment: It's clearly a bug. I just reported it. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2288

Comment: And a PR that fixes it https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19332